# How to import a file into a react app that uses create react app as raw text?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

### Goals

1. I want to display some code for reference from the project itself.
2. I want the display of the code to be updated with the implementation.
3. I don't want to eject from `create-react-app`

This react project, created with `create-react-app` and typescript, is going to be used to display some custom components for re-use in other projects. My goal is to have the component be used right next to the code that is using it.

How can I load the file if I don't have access to the webpack config, and I can't use `fs.readFile`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I managed to get this working after a bit of looking around. There are two major pieces that had to be in place to make it work.

### Use the appropriate loader

In this case I wanted to use the `raw-loader`, so I installed it as a dev dependency. `yarn add -D raw-loader`.

In order to actually import the file I needed to then override the webpack configuration like this:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-webpack-loader-syntax
import toolbarItems from '!!raw-loader!../ToolbarItems';
```

This loads the entire file into the variable toolbarItems. By using the `!!` before the loader I  prevent any other webpack loaders from processing it in this specific case. This might work on its own in a plain javascript project, but in typescript...

### You must provide a module to typescript

I was running into the typescript error:

```
Failed to compile.

/Users/cory/Code/something/custom-theme/src/pages/NavigationDemo.tsx
TypeScript error in /Users/cory/Code/something/custom-theme/src/pages/NavigationDemo.tsx(9,26):
Cannot find module '!!raw-loader!../ToolbarItems'.  TS2307

     7 |
     8 | // eslint-disable-next-line import/no-webpack-loader-syntax
  >  9 | import toolbarItems from '!!raw-loader!../ToolbarItems';
       |                          ^
    10 |
    11 | const useStyles = makeStyles({
    12 |   root: {
```

Simply declaring a module for the loader in a file called `ToolbarItems.ts.d.ts` solved the issue for me:

```
declare module '!!raw-loader!*' {
  const content: string;
  export default content;
}
```

[source](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader/issues/56#issuecomment-507057511)

Comment: +1 yes, I do this too. But how to do you test the resulting react app with Jest? How can I teach Jest to understand the !!raw-loader! directive?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an answer for you there. But be sure to report back if you figure it out!

Comment: @counterbeing I believe you are missing an ! in the typing file. `!!raw-loader`

Comment: Thanks for the catch @Pooya, updated.

Comment: Doesn't work for me with CRA 5.0.1 it changes the content of the file, but the imported string is still a url from which you have to fetch the file content.

Comment: @SashaDavydenko I've abandoned CRA for vite, but if you come up with a solution that works, I'm happy to put a header at the top of the current answer and upvote you :)

Answer (score 6):

Since you use create-react-app for your project, the best solution at the moment would be a babel plugin called Raw.Macro.

This plugin allows you to access content of your files without a need to create-react-app eject. Provides really elegant solution without any boilerplate code and declaring "d.ts" files as in previous answer.

Note: There is a small drawback that you have to re-start your webpack dev server when the file changes, because the content of a file is being embedded during the build process.

```
import raw from 'raw.macro';

function foo(){
    const jsonContent = raw('../utils/stops.json');
    console.log(jsonContent);
}
```

Comment: what about a solution for VITE?